# How to pass a context as a parameter

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm an beginner in kotlin and im trying to pass a context as a parameter, but isnt working...
these are my codes:

**FUNCTION saveDatabase**

```
    private fun saveDatabase(context : Context){
    val fightersName = Match(1, fighter1.toString(), fighter2.toString(),
            minute.toInt(), round.toInt())

    val db = DBContract(context)
    db.insertData(fightersName)
    }
```

**CALLING THE FUNCTION**

```
   saveDatabase(context)
```

**WARNING**

> Typemismatch 
>   Required: Context
>   Found: Context?

This class is a fragment that extends of a Fragment()

Comment: The parameter you're passing to the method is nullable `Context?` and the method only accepts not nullable `Context` type. Just ensure the context is not nullable by checking it before. `saveDatabase(context!!)` wouldn't give you any compiler errors, but you should check it's nullability before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function requires a **non null** Context object, whereas you are calling it with a nullable and mutable Context object. If you are sure your context is not null, call

```
saveDatabase(context!!)
```

**!!** means that you vouch for the object to be non null

Or you can check your function for safety, then change your function to

```
private fun saveDatabase(context : Context?){
    if(context != null){
    val fightersName = Match(1, fighter1.toString(), fighter2.toString(),
            minute.toInt(), round.toInt())

    val db = DBContract(context)
    db.insertData(fightersName)
    }
    }
```

Comment: The only way to check whether the context is null or not is how @zsmb13 has answered. I repeat this method is perfect receiving not nullable context. When you say "If you are sure your context is not null, call", the only way is checking it before thus, Kotlin will inference the caller parameter as not nullable.

Comment: Better not use `Context?` in your function if you don't need to handle the `else` part. That is just overkill. Your `saveDatabase(context!!)` answer is already enough.

Answer (score 1):

The [`getContext`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getContext()) method that you're accessing as the `context` property in Kotlin has a nullable type `Context?` - since it will return `null` when your `Fragment` isn't attached to an `Activity`.

One way to deal with the error is to first fetch its value, and perform a null check before you call your function:

```
val context = context
if (context != null) {
    saveDatabase(context)
}
```

The same check [using `let`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#execute-if-not-null), in two different forms:

```
context?.let { ctx -> saveDatabase(ctx) }
context?.let { saveDatabase(it) }
```

You can also use [`requireContext`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#requirecontext) if you are absolutely sure that your `Fragment` is attached to an `Activity` - this returns a non-nullable `Context`, or throws an exception if there isn't one available.

```
saveDatabase(requireContext())
```

Answer (score 0):

it so easy. Try as follow

```
private fun saveDatabase(context : Context?){
    val fightersName = Match(1, fighter1.toString(), fighter2.toString(),
            minute.toInt(), round.toInt())

    val db = DBContract(context)
    db.insertData(fightersName)
}
```

Comment: I don't quite like this answer. You're just spreading the context nullability when DBContract perhaps shouldn't receive a nullable Context. This method is correct receiving a not nullable Context. The check should be done before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in Android with kotlin you will surely need an "always available" context. This is the way:

```
class App : Application() {
companion object {
    lateinit var instance: App
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    instance = this
}
```

}

then you just need to pass:

```
val db = DBContract(App.instance)
```

Be sure of modifying the manifest:

```
 <application
    android:name=".App"
    ...>
```